# How to sort list in excel when you want to preserve groupings

Tags: excel

I've got a excel spreadsheet of imported broken links with their parent page. I need to sort by the error code, i.e. find all broken links with the error code 404. The issue I'm having is that I need to know what parent page they are coming from after the sort. Below is a screenshot, the parent page is the first URL at A1 and then every URL without an error code next to it (A19, A23,A33 in the screenshot). The links below the parent URL belong to that parent page.

So how would I sort by error code and be able to see what the parent page is for the links after the sort?

[image]

Comment: The question as asked was answered, but after changing the data this question arises.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that with deleting blank rows (filter may be easiest for this) and inserting a column on the extreme left with `=B1` in A1 and in A2 copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),B1,A1)
```

met the requirement.